# how to update row

Tags: sql

I hv a table like this:-

```
ID    Model     Value
DAX   FAB01     
DAZ   FAB01
DAA   FAB01
DAX   FAB02     
DAZ   FAB02
DAA   FAB02
```

I need to update the table so that the final output will be like this:-

```
ID    Model     Value
DAX   FAB01     123
DAZ   FAB01     789  
DAA   FAB01     963
DAX   FAB02     456
DAZ   FAB02     951
DAA   FAB02     753
```

I tried the below:-

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET VALUE = CASE
              WHEN MODEL='FAB01' AND ID='DAX' THEN '123'
              WHEN MODEL='FAB01' AND ID='DAZ' THEN '789'
              WHEN MODEL='FAB01' AND ID='DAA' THEN '963'
              WHEN MODEL='FAB02' AND ID='DAX' THEN '456'
              WHEN MODEL='FAB02' AND ID='DAX' THEN '951'
              WHEN MODEL='FAB02' AND ID='DAX' THEN '753'
              ELSE VALUE
            END
```

Re-run the above & it works now.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting the value from someother table or column?

Comment: nope. The value is from Excel.

Answer (score 3):

```
   UPDATE [TABLENAME]
   SET VALUE = 123

   WHERE ID = "DAX" AND MODEL = "FAB01"
```

Etc..repeat for each row

Comment: DAX = 123 for FAB01 but for FAB02, DAX = 456. How ??

Comment: I think the unique id is Model (ie FAB01, FAB02). The problem is i hv a long list to update as the Model number starts from FAB01 to FAB99. Your suggested method is 'one-by-one'. Is there a shorten way ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that with a faster way because the data's were from excel so you have to assign every data to the correct row.. Sorry.. But maybe somebody know a special thing..

Answer (score 2):

Extending from the bAN's answer. The update should be -

```
UPDATE [TABLENAME]
SET [VALUE] = 123
WHERE ID = 'DAX'
AND Model = 'FAB01'
```

The uniqueness is on two columns in the table (ID and Model).

Answer (score 2):

All statements:

```
UPDATE YourTableName SET [Value] = 123 WHERE [ID] = 'DAX' AND [model] = 'FAB01'
GO

UPDATE YourTableName SET [Value] = 789 WHERE [ID] = 'DAZ' AND [model] = 'FAB01'
GO

UPDATE YourTableName SET [Value] = 963 WHERE [ID] = 'DAA' AND [model] = 'FAB01'
GO

UPDATE YourTableName SET [Value] = 456 WHERE [ID] = 'DAX' AND [model] = 'FAB02'     
GO

UPDATE YourTableName SET [Value] = 951 WHERE [ID] = 'DAZ' AND [model] = 'FAB02'
GO

UPDATE YourTableName SET [Value] = 753 WHERE [ID] = 'DAA' AND [model] = 'FAB02'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you might try to use `OPENROWSET()`. Here's an example:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Value = xls.ExcelColumnValue
FROM OPENROWSET(...) xls
WHERE YourTable.ID    = xls.ExcelColumnID
  AND YourTable.Model = xls.ExcelColumnModel
```

All column names after `xls.` are arbitrary here, you should replace them with the actual column names. Basically, you can find them out simply with `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(...)`. (You can also know them in advance following the information below.)

Now for the `...` part. Here you define the source, in particular you specify the file format, the file name, the sheet name, and also you specify the middle tier software to be used, whatever that means, and some properties of the source. Depending on what Excel version is used you can try the following variants:

- for Excel 97-2003:

```
OPENROWSET (
  'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
  'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\path\file.xls', 
  'SELECT * FROM [sheet name$]'
)
```

- for Excel 2007+:

```
OPENROWSET (
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\path\file.xls',
  'SELECT * FROM [sheet name$]'
)
```

Replace the italics accordingly with the actual file name and sheet name.

The `HDR=YES;` option specifies that the first row defines the column names. If in your case the first row contains data like all the other rows, simply drop this option.